# return XML file to user

Tags: asp.net, file

I am creating a XML file which I want to return to the user, when the user goes to a specified location. I have thought of something like:

```
 return new FileStream("questions.xml",FileMode.Open);
```

Is this the proper code, or how would you return a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    var file = Server.MapPath("~/questions.xml");
    Response.WriteFile(file);
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=questions.xml");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I might encounter scenarios when the file questions.xml is modified while it is downloaded by a user. To solve this, what should I do? Is there any solution which does not require the file to be saved?

Comment: @Ryan, you could directly generate and serve the file from memory without ever saving it to disk. Instead of `Response.WriteFile`, use `Response.Write` and pass the XML contents or write directly to the `Response.OutputStream`.